# SwiftUI - Why can't I use an Alert within an if statement

Tags: if-statement, swiftui, alert

I'm currently working through the #100daysofswiftUI and have a quick question regarding the use of alerts within if statements. This particular task is at the end of the second project.

Here is the code:

```
.alert(isPresented: $showingScore) {
    if x == 1 {
        Alert(title: Text(scoreTitle), message: Text("The correct answer was \(countries[correctAnswer])"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Restart")) {
                self.askQuestion()
        })
    }
}
```

I feel like this code should work however I have a yellow alert over the Alert line saying:

> Result of 'Alert' initializer is unused

I don't know what this means, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return an `Alert` in the `.alert` modifier, not an if statement.

For this you can create a computed property which returns an Alert:

```
var alert: Alert {
    if x == 1 {
        return Alert(
            title: Text(scoreTitle),
            message: Text("The correct answer was \(countries[correctAnswer])"),
            dismissButton: .default(Text("Restart")) {
                self.askQuestion()
            }
        )
    } else {
        return Alert(...) // return some other `Alert`
    }
}
```

and use it in the `.alert` modifier:

```
.alert(isPresented: $showingScore) {
    alert
}
```

Just make sure you only enable `showingScore` when you want to show an alert.

Answer (score 0):

you should put your `if` condition with `showingScore`,
do something like this

```
if x == 1 {
  showingScore = true
}
```

your alert will look like this

```
.alert(isPresented: $showingScore) {
        Alert(title: Text(scoreTitle), message: Text("The correct answer was \(countries[correctAnswer])"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Restart")) {
                    self.askQuestion()
            })
    }
```